# GTKMM/C++ Window Event on losing/regaining focus?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtkmm

How can I call a function whenever my GTKMM app loses or regains focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect handlers to the window's [focus-in-event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-in-event) and [focus-out-event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-out-event).